# Unable to undertstand usage of $spacer in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a problem with understanding the [$spacer](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) variable(?) noted in [Bootstrap 4's Spacing Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) and couldn't find any documentation on it.

For example: `1 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * .25`

```
.ml-1 {
  margin-left: ($spacer * .25) !important;
}
```

What I understand is the value of the variable is to be multiplied by 0.25, but how is that possible if the value is not even set?

Comment: and you read this `You can add more sizes by adding entries to the $spacers Sass map variable` ?

Comment: Yes I read that, but couldn't find it in the code. 
I finally managed to find the location of that variable: ...\MDB Free\scss\core\bootstrap\_variables.scss

Thanks anyway Temani Afif. =)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the variable wasn't set then it wouldn't be possible… but since it **is** set ([right here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/99379f3843ddd5bd66ce6559ab91ef68c744fbd7/scss/_variables.scss#L118)), that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 6):

As Quentin pointed,
The default value of $spacer is 1rem, i.e 16 pixels for most of the browsers.
You can evaluate the outcome by multiplying 16 * the fraction( .25, .5 etc), and cross-check the result in Devtool's  CSSBox Model.Consider the below example,

```
    <form class="form-inline ">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    </form>
```

As we use ***mr-sm-2*** class on the input field,
Which essentially says, set the right margin to size 2 on small breakpoint( between 576px to 767 px)

> Now, if you check the right margin of the subject element, it will be
>   16 * .5 = 8px.

Answer (score 4):

$spacer is a sass variable . its value is 16px
in Bootstrap for example `ml-1` mean `margin-left` with size 1
whose value is (`$spacer * 0.25`) i.e `16px*0.25` which is 1/4th value of 16px
== 4px,
therefore a size 1 for padding or margin stands for "`$spacer * .25`" :`4px.`

For size 2: `$spacer * .5`== `16px*0.5` == `8px`.
now..

size 3: `$spacer*1` [the exact value] == `16px`.

size 4: `$spacer*1.5`==`24px`.

size 5: `$spacer*3` == `48px`

Comment: To be precise it is **not** `16px`; it is `1rem`.